# Update/toggle/filter bar graph based on user's <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Using d3.js I want to build an interactive bar graph which allows the user to visualize/filter data based on multiple data sets.

Let's say my datasets show different data about five companies and daughter companies, always totalling to 100. i.e:

```
index.tsv:
Company    Births   Deaths 
A          10       90
B          15       85
C          1        99
D          8        92
E          7        93

equality.tsv:
Company    Women    Men
A          45       55
B          70       30
C          90       10
D          50       50
E          7        93

equality_daughter.tsv:
Company    Women    Men
A          45       55
B          70       30
C          90       10
D          50       50
E          7        93

salary.tsv:
Company    High salary  Low salary
A          45           55
B          70           30
C          90           10
D          50           50
E          7            93

salary_daughter.tsv:
Company    High salary  Low salary
A          45           55
B          70           30
C          90           10
D          50           50
E          7            93
```

I want the user to select dataset to visualize in two steps: 1. equality or salary? 2. main or daugther company? I (think?) I can accomplish some of this using:

```
<select>
  <option value="index">Home</option>
  <option value="equality">Gender equality</option>
  <option value="salary">The Money</option>
</select>
```

So when user selects Home, I want a bar graph of the index to show, and so forth.

I'm basically looking for easiest way to accomplish this. I was thinking about using ajax to fetch the data based on selection:

```
var url = "data/" + option.this + ".tsv";
                            $.ajax({
                                cache: true,
                                dataType: "text",
                                url: url
                            })
```

But not sure if this is the best way to go. Also, being a rookie, not sure how to combine this with d3 so it updates the graph on change. This setup: http://www.theguardian.com/sport/interactive/2013/jan/30/nfl-salaries-team-position#philadelphia-eagles,buffalo-bills shows several different versions of the functions I'm looking for.

So, I'm basically looking for any pointers (i.e. what do read up on) and suggestions/solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d3 has a built-in method for fetching and parsing TSV files: [`d3.tsv()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#tsv).

This function accepts a file path as its primary argument

```
d3.tsv('path/to/your/file.tsv')
```

You can specify a callback function either as a second argument...

```
d3.tsv('path/to/your/file.tsv', function(error, rows) {
  // code to make chart goes here...
  // parsed tsv data is now an Array of Objects named 'rows'
  //  with each Array element representing one row of tsv data
});
```

...or you can use the `.get` method to specify the callback.

```
d3.tsv('path/to/your/file.tsv').get(function(error, rows) {
  // same as above
});
```

The API also allows for an additional function to be passed, which is the *accessor* function. This function will be run once for each row of tsv data, and allows you to make adjustments to the incoming data, for instance to change the format of dates or numbers. To specify an accessor function, either add a middle argument to `d3.tsv` (making the callback the third argument)...

```
d3.tsv('path/to/your/file.tsv', function(d) {
  // this is the accessor
  //  'd' is an Object representing a single row of tsv data
  // this function should return an Object
}, function(error, rows) {
  // this is the callback
});
```

...or you can use the `.row` method to specify the accessor.

```
d3.tsv('path/to/your/file.tsv')
  .row(function(d) {
    // accessor function
  })
  .get(function(error, rows) {
    // callback function
  });
```

---

To implement this in your case, using the select, you will want to add an event listener to run some code when the selection is changed. Since it looks like you're using jQuery, this should be pretty simple to do. First, add an ID to the select element so you can access it directly. Something like this should do the trick:

*HTML*

```
<select id="select-data">
  <option value="index">Home</option>
  <option value="equality">Gender equality</option>
  <option value="salary">The Money</option>
</select>
```

*JavaScript*

```
// this runs when the select is changed
$('#select-data').change(function() {
  // store the selected value in a variable
  var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  // now use the selection to fetch the correct data file
  d3.tsv('path/to/' + selected + '.tsv')
    .row(function(d) {
      // accessor function
    })
    .get(function(error, rows) {
      // call your render of the chart using the new data from here
    });
});
```

You can read up some more on the API for this [**here**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV). I hope that helps.